# Shiny Package in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am practicing shiny package in R. I was creating an app where the user selects two variables and decides the degree of a curve that is to be fit on the corresponding scatterplot. I'm using the mtcars data for this purpose. I used the selectinput command for getting the variables. I want the sliderinput command to decide the degree of the fitting curve. The code seems to be working except for the sliderinput command.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel('Fitting a curve'),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "xcol",label = "X-Axis",choices = names(mtcars)),
    selectInput(inputId = "ycol",label = "Y-Axis",choices = names(mtcars),selected = names(mtcars)[[3]]),
    sliderInput(inputId = "degree",label = "Degree of fit",min = 0,max = 2,value = 0)
  ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))

)

server <- function(input,output){
  x <- reactive({mtcars[,input$xcol]})
  y <- reactive({mtcars[,input$ycol]})
  z <- renderPrint({ifelse(input$degree==0,lm(y()~),ifelse(input$degree==1,lm(y()~x()),lm(y()~x()+x()^2)))})
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(x(),y(),col = "red")
    abline(z())
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

Pretty sure there's an error in the "z" line in the server part. Please help I'm new to the shiny package.

Comment: You can fit using only the intercept by doing `lm(y()~1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use `ifelse` here, `if (...) {...} else {...}` is much better (and it won't break things). Why? Compare these two:

   ```r
   mdl1 <- ifelse(1 == 1, lm(mpg~disp, data=mtcars), lm(mpg~disp+cyl, data=mtcars))
   class(mdl1)
   # [1] "list"
   mdl1
   # [[1]]
   # (Intercept)        disp 
   # 29.59985476 -0.04121512 

   mdl2 <- if (1 == 1) lm(mpg~disp, data=mtcars) else lm(mpg~disp+cyl, data=mtcars)
   class(mdl2)
   # [1] "lm"
   mdl2
   # Call:
   # lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
   # Coefficients:
   # (Intercept)         disp  
   #    29.59985     -0.04122
   ```
2. You should be getting an error with this, and you should include that verbatim in your question. In this case, I see `unexpected ')' in ...`. I found `lm(y()~)`. You need dependent variables or at least `1`, changing that to `lm(y()~1)` fixes that typo.
3. Not crushing you here (yet), but it's good practice to `req`uire your reactive variables are stable and not `NULL` before using them. At a minimum, read [`?req`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/req.html); for a little more control and user-friendliness, read [`?validate`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/validate.html).

See if this works better:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel('Fitting a curve'),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "xcol",label = "X-Axis",choices = names(mtcars)),
    selectInput(inputId = "ycol",label = "Y-Axis",choices = names(mtcars),selected = names(mtcars)[[3]]),
    sliderInput(inputId = "degree",label = "Degree of fit",min = 0,max = 2,value = 0)
  ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))

)

server <- function(input,output){
  x <- reactive({mtcars[,input$xcol]})
  y <- reactive({mtcars[,input$ycol]})
  z <- reactive({
    req(input$degree, x(), y())
    if (input$degree == 0) {
      lm(y() ~ 1)
    } else if (input$degree == 1) {
      lm(y() ~ x())
    } else lm(y() ~ x() + x()^2)
  })         
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(x(),y(),col = "red")
    abline(z())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

Comment: The constant model thing was a typo error on my part. Apologies. The code given is working as well. Thanks. However, I don't seem to understand the req and validate function details from the help menu. Is there a better explanation given somewhere? Perhaps via a video link?

Comment: `req` will gracefully exit a reactive chunk if its arguments are not "truthy" (in short: not null, some semblance of value). This is often required in more complicated shiny apps, where a block may fire before an input field is instantiated (which causes its value to be `NULL` even if the input is defined to always have some value). Also, you can skip execution of a block if other conditions are not true. Consider `req(cond)` the same as wrapping the entire reactive block internals with `if (!is.null(cond)) { ... }` where `is.null` is really just *one* of the tests `req` conducts.

Comment: ... and `validate` can produce the same effect, but offers you an ability to inform the user of something, in a nice way. (`req` is silent.)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    headerPanel('Fitting a curve'),
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(inputId = "xcol",label = "X-Axis",choices = names(mtcars)),
        selectInput(inputId = "ycol",label = "Y-Axis",choices = names(mtcars),selected = names(mtcars)[[3]]),
        sliderInput(inputId = "degree",label = "Degree of fit",min = 0,max = 2,value = 0)
    ),
    mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot1")
        )

)

server <- function(input,output){

    x <- reactive({
        mtcars[,input$xcol]
    })

    y <- reactive({
        mtcars[,input$ycol]
    })

    z <- reactive({
        if(input$degree==0){
            return(lm(y()~1))
        }else if(input$degree == 1){
            return(lm(y()~x()))
        }else{
            return(lm(y()~x()+x()^2))
        }
    })

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        plot(x(),y(),col = "red")
        abline(z())
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```